# Trying to combine two dataframes together but being thrown an error

Tags: r, shiny

So I have two data frames that I am attempting to combine together. The two DFs share the following characteristics:

1. They have the same number of columns
2. Column names are the same
3. Equal amount of rows (100 each)

So the first column in each table is ID. One table has ID # 1 through 100 while the next one has ID # 101 through 200.

I have attempted to use the rbind function but it will throw an error that I can't figure out how to get around:

```
data3 <- rbind(data1,data2)
```

The error reads:

```
Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to work around this?

Ultimately, I want them to be combined in to one single dataframe of IDs 1 through 200 and all the corresponding data in the columns.

So say data1 looks like:

```
 ID    Team       Position
 1     Pirates    Pitcher
 2     Yankees    Catcher
 3     Red Sox    Outfield
```

And data2 looks like:

```
ID    Team       Position
 4     Astros    Pitcher
 5     Brewers   First
 6     Dodgers   Shortstop
```

I want the final result (data3) to look like:

```
ID     Team      Position
 1     Pirates   Pitcher
 2     Yankees   Catcher
 3     Red Sox   Outfield
 4     Astros    Pitcher
 5     Brewers   First
 6     Dodgers   Shortstop
```

By the way, these are not the names or data I'm working with. Just more of a simplified example.

Comment: what about just setting the row.names to NULL it doens't look like you are storing valuable information in there anyway , `rownames(data1) <- NULL`

Comment: Can you provide the output of `rownames(data1)` and `rownames(data2)`?

Comment: What do you mean? Like what it actually says?

Comment: I don't see the problem comes from.

Comment: Could you include `str(data1)` and `str(data2)` in your question? Maybe one data.frame contains a factor and the other not.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you want to preserve the row names or not, you can do one of the following:

```
# Do not preserve row names

rownames(data1) <- NULL
rownames(data2) <- NULL

rbind(data1, data2)


# Preserve the row names

data1 <- cbind(rownames(data1), data1)
data2 <- cbind(rownames(data2), data2)

rownames(data1) <- NULL
rownames(data2) <- NULL

rbind(data1, data2)
```

Comment: Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names

Comment: Your error indicates that your two data frames don't have identical columns.  You may consider `dplyr::bind_rows`, which will circumvent the problem, but you should also consider if circumventing the problem is what you want to do.  If one of the data frames has only a subset of the columns, then `bind_rows` may be appropriate.  If the two data frames have radically different column names, more caution may be warranted.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy!  Since R code is very efficient, you can do this with just 3 lines of code.

```
File1 = read.table("C:\\Users\\your_path\\Desktop\\File1.txt")
File2 = read.table("C:\\Users\\your_path\\Desktop\\File2.txt")
All = merge(File1, File2, by.x = "Team", by.y = "Team", all = TRUE)
```